# How to configure admin.py file to see PickledObjectField of django-picklefield snippet

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a simple model

```
class UserNotification(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey('profiles.user', unique=True)
    notifications = PickledObjectField()
```

When I make some objects of this model and see in admin panel I only see user field and not notification field. How do the modify the admin.py to see it too. I am using the following in admin.py

```
admin.site.register(models.UserNotification)
```

Comment: Where do you want to see the notifications ? in the list view or change view of admin ?

Comment: @SachinGupta 
 
I had like to see in change view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class UserNotification(TimeStampedModel):
   user = models.ForeignKey('profiles.user', unique=True)
   notifications = PickledObjectField()

    def notifications_unpacked(self):
        return u'{notifications}'.format(notifications=self.notifications)


class UserNotificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user','notifications_unpacked',)
```

Comment: OP says he liked to see in change view.